# f# discriminated union generic

Tags: generics, f#, discriminated-union

What is the syntax for a generic TryValue type that can return a Value of 'a or an Error of 'b?

```
type TryValue =
    | Value of 'a
    | Error of 'b
```

If error is a string then it's fine:

```
type 'a TryValue =
    | Value of 'a
    | Error of string
```

I'd like to define a tryRun function that takes an error creator, a function and a parameter that will try to run the function with the parameter and on any error use the error creator function to create an error:

```
let tryRun createErrorFn param fn =
    try 
        Value (fn param)
    with
        | ex  -> Error (createErrorFn ex.Message param)
```

And a wrapper for any function to be wrapped by a tryRun:

```
let wrapTryRun createErrorFn fn param =
    match param with
    | Value a -> tryRun createErrorFn a fn
    | Error e -> Error e
```

Now I can run a list of functions (pseudo code, have not yet fully worked this out):

```
let createErrorFn errorMessage param =
    URLProcessignError {url=param.url;errorMessage=errorMessage}
[fn1;fn2] |> List.fold (fun acc fn -> (wrapTryRun createErrorFn fn acc))
```

Comment: looks like there's result type in [F# 4.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/25/a-peek-into-f-4-1/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the generic parameters in the left side:

```
type TryValue<'a,'b> =
    | Value of 'a
    | Error of 'b
```

When it's only one parameter you can use the ML style as you did in the case of a string, but if you have more than one parameter you should use the .NET notation with the `<` `>` angle brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the old ML style can also be used with more than one type parameter by specifying a tuple:

```
type ('a, 'b) TryValue =
    | Value of 'a
    | Error of 'b
```

However, I believe I read the old syntax is deprecated…

Comment: I don't think it's really deprecated, just not advised for your own types. Many people follow the compiler's usual output syntax, which uses ML style for some built-in types like list and option and C# style for other types; I personally prefer to use C# style everywhere for consistency.

Comment: The ml style comes in handy when converting ML to F#. If the ML style was depreciated it would be harder to convert ML to F#.